# Reading Excel File from Google Cloud Storage and converting to CSV

Tags: apache-poi, google-cloud-storage

I have implemented reading and converting to CSV from Excel File using Apache POI library successfully (where file is present in any of my local Windows folder) .
In my current scenario, I have to read the file from cloud storage bucket (gs://xyz/abc.xlsx),convert to CSV and store the file back to GCS.
Is there any way by which I can make my code identify the file present in Google Cloud?
Any leads will be appreciated.

There are Java APIs to communicate with GCS but I'm finding any way around to provide the path of GCS File to parameterized constructor of 'XSSFWorkbook'. Please find the snippet below which I'm using for converting an Excel file to CSV.

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\balajeev\\Desktop\\abc.xlsx"));
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\balajeev\\Desktop\\abc.csv"),
                                      true);
    for (Sheet sheet : wb) {
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            boolean firstCell = true;
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if ( ! firstCell ) out.print(',');
                String text = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                out.print(text);
                firstCell = false;
            }
            out.println();
        }
    }
```

How to make this code recognise a file present in GCS,convert it to CSV and post conversion put the converted file in GCS.

Comment: Find a good Java library for talking to GCS, then integrate that with your existing code?

Comment: Edited my question. Could you please look at and provide me a little specific answer? @Gagravarr